# Missing properties error when using Sequelize association

Tags: node.js, typescript, types, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize in TypeScript to implement an API in Express. I'm encountering a type-related error when using the value returned by an association mixin.

Here is a portion of my data model as I've defined it:

```
export class User extends Model {
  id!: number;
  username!: string;
  email!: string;
  password!: string;
  active!: boolean;

  createdAt!: Date;
  updatedAt!: Date;
}

export class UserSession extends Model {
  token!: string;
  userId!: number;
  expiresAt!: Date;
  renewalHours!: number;

  getUser!: BelongsToGetAssociationMixin<User>;
}
```

Here is how I'm attempting to authenticate a request during a session (within an Express middleware):

```
UserSession.findOne({ where: { token: req.body.token }, include: [User] })
  .then(session => {
    if (session) {
      const now = moment();
      if (session.expiresAt > now.toDate()) {
        session.set('expiresAt',
                    now.add(session.renewalHours, 'hours').toDate());
        session.save();

        req.user = session.getUser();
        next();
      } else {
        session.destroy();
        res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Session expired' });
      }
    } else {
      res.status(403).json({ msg: 'Not logged in' });
    }
  });
```

I have associated `UserSession` with `User` via `UserSession.belongsTo(User)` (details omitted).

The particular line

```
req.user = session.getUser();
```

produces the following error from TypeScript:

```
 Type 'Bluebird<User>' is missing the following properties from type 'User': id, username, email, password, and 26 more.
```

`req` is an Express `Request`. I've added a `user` field to it (for purposes of TypeScript) as follows:

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
      user?: User;
      session?: UserSession;
    }
  }
}
```

I know that Sequelize is now built upon the Bluebird Promise framework, so I suspect this has to do with my type definitions. It seems like TypeScript doesn't think that `UserSession.getUser` will return something with `User`'s attributes. Why not?

Answer (score 0):

As predicted, this was a very simple misunderstanding of the way Sequelize's mixin functions work. As with everything in Sequelize, they are of course asynchronous calls using Bluebird! Therefore, `UserSession.getUser` doesn't return `User` but rather a Promise that will return user. The line is fixed as follows:

```
req.user = await session.getUser();
```

and of course marking this function as `async`. This could also be done using `session.getUser().then( ... )`.